# Attempt to invoke interface method boolean com.facebook.CallbackManager...on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, facebook, react-native

When I choose an image from the device image gallery I get this error

```
Process: com.vepo, PID: 5996
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=13002, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/12 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.vepo/com.vepo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.facebook.CallbackManager.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.facebook.CallbackManager.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.vepo.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:21)
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
09-24 02:57:17.871  5996  5996 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 9 more
```

And when I log in with facebook I get this error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.vepo, PID: 6181
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.vepo/com.vepo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.facebook.CallbackManager.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.facebook.CallbackManager.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.vepo.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:21)
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
09-24 03:00:12.367  6181  6181 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 9 more
09-24 03:00:12.368   628  2208 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.vepo/.MainActivity
```

I think they might be different errors caused by the same thing, because I have just added the facebook sdk.

The code that these errors refer to is probably **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.vepo;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
 import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        MainApplication.getCallbackManager().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    mCallbackManager = new CallbackManager.Factory().create();
    ReactPackage packages[] = new ReactPackage[]{
        new MainReactPackage(),
        new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
    };
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(packages);
}

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "vepo";
    }
}
```

and **MainApplication.java**

```
package com.vepo;

import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.chirag.RNMail.RNMail;
import com.cmcewen.blurview.BlurViewPackage;
import com.wix.interactable.Interactable;
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
    return mCallbackManager;
  }

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new FBSDKPackage(getCallbackManager()),
          new BlurViewPackage(),
          new Interactable(),
          new ImagePickerPackage(),
          new VectorIconsPackage(),
          new RNMail(),
          new MapsPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    // If you want to use AppEventsLogger to log events.
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

I'm sure I'm making a noob mistake. Anyone see what is wrong?

Here is my **AndroidManifest.xml** for good measure

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vepo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
 <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="xxx"/>
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
          <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>






</manifest>
```

Comment: try create before call in `onActivityResult`: `CallbackManager mCallbackManager = new CallbackManager.Factory().create();`

Comment: I think you need to remove `mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` line because it is the older version of react-native implementation.

Comment: @bennygenel Yes, it works!! Thanks!

Comment: @bennygenel thumbs up!